# Error CoordinatorLayout

Tags: java, android

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            // CONTEUDO LINEAR LAYOUT

        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerViewListaClientes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
                android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Add in Activity Manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

I am Brazilian. Sorry with my English

When the keyboard opens and Toolbar is hidden, the toolbar disappears.

This only happens when the keyboard is open and Toolbar is hidden.

Before to open keyboard :

[Image Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2wVk.png)

After to open keyboard :

[Image After - Bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAVRG.png)

Comment: Try to add `android:isScrollContainer="false"` to your `CoordinatorLayout`.

Comment: it continued with the problem

Comment: Video bug - http://sendvid.com/gffll5yj